# Unable to find the requested .Net Framework Data Provider. PostgreSQL and Mono

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, mono, dotconnect

I have a problem with my application wrote in Visual Studio. Build in Visual Studio is OK, but when I try to run on Mono. Server shows

```
System.ArgumentException
Unable to find the requested .Net Framework Data Provider.  It may not be installed.
```

[image]

I use EntityFramework 6 and dotConnect for PosgreSQL.

Here is my Web.Config:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!--
    For more information on how to configure your ASP.NET application, please visit
    http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=301880
    -->
<configuration>
    <configSections>
        <!-- For more information on Entity Framework configuration, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=237468 -->
        <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
    </configSections>
    <connectionStrings>
        <!--<add name="PostgreEntitiesConnectionString" connectionString="metadata=res://*/Models.Entities.DataModel1.csdl|res://*/Models.Entities.DataModel1.ssdl|res://*/Models.Entities.DataModel1.msl;provider=Devart.Data.PostgreSql;provider connection string=&quot;User Id=postgres;Host=192.168.50.89;Database=postgres;Initial Schema=public&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />-->
        <add name="EntityManager" connectionString="User Id=postgres;Password=****;Host=127.0.0.1;Database=postgres; Charset=utf8; Persist Security Info=True;Initial Schema=public" providerName="Devart.Data.PostgreSql" /></connectionStrings>
    <appSettings>
        <add key="webpages:Version" value="3.0.0.0" />
        <add key="webpages:Enabled" value="false" />
        <add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true" />
        <add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true" />
    </appSettings>
    <system.web>
        <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.6" />
        <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.6" />
        <customErrors mode="Off" />
        <httpModules>
            <add name="ApplicationInsightsWebTracking" type="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Web.ApplicationInsightsHttpModule, Microsoft.AI.Web" />
        </httpModules>
    </system.web>
    <runtime>
        <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
            <dependentAssembly>
                <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Helpers" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
                <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
            </dependentAssembly>
            <dependentAssembly>
                <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.WebPages" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
                <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
            </dependentAssembly>
            <dependentAssembly>
                <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Mvc" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
                <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-5.2.3.0" newVersion="5.2.3.0" />
            </dependentAssembly>
        </assemblyBinding>
    </runtime>
    <system.webServer>
        <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />
        <modules>
            <remove name="ApplicationInsightsWebTracking" />
            <add name="ApplicationInsightsWebTracking" type="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Web.ApplicationInsightsHttpModule, Microsoft.AI.Web" preCondition="managedHandler" />
        </modules>
    </system.webServer>
    <entityFramework>
        <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.LocalDbConnectionFactory, EntityFramework">
            <parameters>
                <parameter value="mssqllocaldb" />
            </parameters>
        </defaultConnectionFactory>
        <providers>
            <provider invariantName="Devart.Data.PostgreSql" type="Devart.Data.PostgreSql.Entity.PgSqlEntityProviderServices, Devart.Data.PostgreSql.Entity.EF6, Version=7.5.644.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=09af7300eec23701" />
        </providers>
    </entityFramework>
    <system.codedom>
        <compilers>
            <!--
            <compiler language="c#;cs;csharp" extension=".cs" type="Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.CSharpCodeProvider, Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" warningLevel="4" compilerOptions="/langversion:6 /nowarn:1659;1699;1701" />
            <compiler language="vb;vbs;visualbasic;vbscript" extension=".vb" type="Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.VBCodeProvider, Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" warningLevel="4" compilerOptions="/langversion:14 /nowarn:41008 /define:_MYTYPE=\&quot;Web\&quot; /optionInfer+" />
            -->
        </compilers>
    </system.codedom>
    <system.data>
        <DbProviderFactories>
            <!--<add name="dotConnect for PostgreSQL" invariant="Devart.Data.PostgreSql" description="Devart dotConnect for PostgreSQL" type="Devart.Data.PostgreSql.PgSqlProviderFactory, Devart.Data.PostgreSql, Version= 7.5.639.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=09af7300eec23701" />-->
        </DbProviderFactories>
    </system.data>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 0):

Solution is uncomment

```
 <!--<add name="dotConnect for PostgreSQL" invariant="De
```

in system.data-> DbProviderFactories section. Fix versions to current version of Devart.Data.PostgreSql (my is 7.5.639.0) and add this line

```
<remove invariant="Devart.Data.PostgreSql"></remove>
```

before

```
<add name="dotConnect for PostgreSQL" inv....
```

in  system.data-> DbProviderFactories section.

Final Web.config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!--
  For more information on how to configure your ASP.NET application, please visit
  http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=301880
  -->
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <!-- For more information on Entity Framework configuration, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=237468 -->
    <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
  </configSections>
  <connectionStrings>
    <!--<add name="PostgreEntitiesConnectionString" connectionString="metadata=res://*/Models.Entities.DataModel1.csdl|res://*/Models.Entities.DataModel1.ssdl|res://*/Models.Entities.DataModel1.msl;provider=Devart.Data.PostgreSql;provider connection string=&quot;User Id=postgres;Host=192.168.50.89;Database=postgres;Initial Schema=public&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />-->
        <add name="EntityManager" connectionString="User Id=postgres;Password=*****;Host=127.0.0.1;Database=postgres; Charset=utf8; Persist Security Info=True;Initial Schema=public" providerName="Devart.Data.PostgreSql" /></connectionStrings>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="webpages:Version" value="3.0.0.0" />
    <add key="webpages:Enabled" value="false" />
    <add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true" />
    <add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true" />
  </appSettings>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.6" />
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.6" />
    <customErrors mode="Off" />
    <httpModules>
      <add name="ApplicationInsightsWebTracking" type="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Web.ApplicationInsightsHttpModule, Microsoft.AI.Web" />
    </httpModules>
  </system.web>
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Helpers" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.WebPages" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Mvc" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-5.2.3.0" newVersion="5.2.3.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
  <system.webServer>
    <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />
    <modules>
      <remove name="ApplicationInsightsWebTracking" />
      <add name="ApplicationInsightsWebTracking" type="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Web.ApplicationInsightsHttpModule, Microsoft.AI.Web" preCondition="managedHandler" />
    </modules>
  </system.webServer>
  <entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.LocalDbConnectionFactory, EntityFramework">
      <parameters>
        <parameter value="mssqllocaldb" />
      </parameters>
    </defaultConnectionFactory>
    <providers>
      <provider invariantName="Devart.Data.PostgreSql" type="Devart.Data.PostgreSql.Entity.PgSqlEntityProviderServices, Devart.Data.PostgreSql.Entity.EF6, Version=7.5.644.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=09af7300eec23701" />
    </providers>
  </entityFramework>
  <system.codedom>
    <compilers>
      <!--
      <compiler language="c#;cs;csharp" extension=".cs" type="Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.CSharpCodeProvider, Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" warningLevel="4" compilerOptions="/langversion:6 /nowarn:1659;1699;1701" />
      <compiler language="vb;vbs;visualbasic;vbscript" extension=".vb" type="Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.VBCodeProvider, Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" warningLevel="4" compilerOptions="/langversion:14 /nowarn:41008 /define:_MYTYPE=\&quot;Web\&quot; /optionInfer+" />
            -->
    </compilers>
  </system.codedom>

<system.data> 
   <DbProviderFactories>
         <remove invariant="Devart.Data.PostgreSql"></remove>
      <add name="dotConnect for PostgreSQL" invariant="Devart.Data.PostgreSql" description="Devart dotConnect for PostgreSQL" type="Devart.Data.PostgreSql.PgSqlProviderFactory, Devart.Data.PostgreSql, Version= 7.5.644.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=09af7300eec23701" />
    </DbProviderFactories> 
  </system.data></configuration>
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have installed :
[Npgsql PostgreSQL Integration Package](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=RojanskyS.NpgsqlPostgreSQLIntegration)

Install EntityFramework6.Npgsql or relevant NuGet package for you .net version in your startup project.

Add or replace these blocks in yor web.config in web project and app.config in class library.

```
  <entityFramework>
    <providers>
      <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
      <provider invariantName="Npgsql" type="Npgsql.NpgsqlServices, EntityFramework6.Npgsql" />
    </providers>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="Npgsql.NpgsqlConnectionFactory, EntityFramework6.Npgsql" />
  </entityFramework>

<system.data>
    <DbProviderFactories>
      <remove invariant="Npgsql" />
      <add name="Npgsql Provider" invariant="Npgsql" description=".NET Framework Data Provider for PostgreSQL" type="Npgsql.NpgsqlFactory, Npgsql, Version=4.1.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=5d8b90d52f46fda7" />
    </DbProviderFactories>
  </system.data>
```